# Problem about text (letter not complete)

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, edit-mode, text-object, text-editor

I have a problem with the letter "s" and the number "5" (the same form) with this font on Blender :/

It is not complete and don't appeared on my render.

[Pardon my English]

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The font works perfectly, the font borders are present, but there is not the texture.

Comment: @pycoder I think this could legitimately be a problem with blender's interpretation of the font as I have seen this happen with fonts before.

Comment: Was the text converted to mesh already? If not try to change font options, like depth, resolution or offset for a tiny amount, it could probably make font object to change Ngons there a bit so Blender to fill those faces.

Comment: First, Axel, what is the font, and where did you get it? Also, is this effect that you see with the "s" when you type it in when adding a text curve object? What does the same selection look like when you use the same font in a different program, like GIMP?

Comment: Try converting the curve to a mesh, or just substitute the S with a curve with the same shape.

Comment: Converting the curve to a mesh don't works :/ When I extrude the text, the borders are present on the lower part of the "s" but the profil face is empty

Comment: This text has already been realized on Blender without problem ( Beginning of this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wec2CwBH7Q )

Comment: It is all good, I offset the font, really easy ^^ Thanks you all !

Comment: @pycoder It appears that it can *sometimes* be a bug: https://developer.blender.org/T40144